# How to dump raw RTSP stream to FTP?

Tags: ftp, rtsp, dump

Is this even possible? I tried using FFMPEG but it allows me to dump it only to a file on a server host where i dont have much free space, so im wondering if its somehow possible to dump that to some other places like a FTP?

Comment: You could have FFMPEG write to a pipe, and set something up to pipe that content away to a different server e.g. over a TCP socket, and you could probably rig that up as an FTP data connection. But it's likely to be easier to just make some space on your server somehow. (even if you have to e.g. buy more storage for a cloud server temporarily.)

Comment: well, in fact its 24h stream so the costs would be pretty high but i have free FTP server with a lot free space thats why im trying to use it.